# mysqldump/mysql error with WP-DB Manager

Tags: mysql

Hi I am getting an error with the Wordpress WP-DBManager Plugin:

`MYSQL dump path does NOT exist. Please check your mysqldump path under DB Options. If uncertain, contact your server administrator.`

`MYSQL path does NOT exist. Please check your mysql path under DB Options. If uncertain, contact your server administrator.`

IT Server administrator doesn't know what to do.
So I have refered to this article: https://www.hacksparrow.com/wp-dbmanager-error-mysql-dump-path-does-not-exist-please-check-your-mysqldump-path-under-db-options.html

I am running AWS, ubuntu lamp stack - mysql 5.6, php7.0

I have checked /usr/bin and no mysqldump or mysql folder.

In the php.ini folder there is this line `;open_basedir =`

Do I create mysqldump and mysql folders? and set open_basedir to `open_basedir = /usr/bin/` I am not quite sure?

Or based on that article there was modules to add - `<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>...`
I could not find the httpd.conf file, where would I find this file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, imagine trying to revive this fossil...welp. Either way, seems like this issue is still relevant for some people and no answer.

Most, if not all major server will use the following paths that you can put in the DB Options (assuming this problem originated in WP-DBManager)

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysql
```

This will give you the green light you're looking for